# Error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is the first time I am uploading a website online.

[Here](http://www.hawkbirdsports.com/#) is the link.

I am using carousel with four images saved in the same folder.But then also I am getting this error.

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Although this question has been previously asked but then also I am not able to find the solution for my problem.

Comment: Thank you guys for your help. I was able to resolve the problem. The error was because of file name should be IMG_5264.JPG not IMG_5264.jpg

Comment: so you're on a \*NIX system. Windows wouldn't have failed on that since it isn't case-sensitive as \*NIX is

Comment: No. I am using windows only but even I am confused why the error was present since windows in case-insensitive.

Comment: well that is indeed the strangest thing I ever saw.

Answer (score -1):

The `404` error means that the file that you are trying to access, which is the background image in the subsequent slides in the carousel, are not present in the server, i.e., they haven't been uploaded.

Please check if they've been uploaded successfully.

Comment back here if any update.